# How can I remove individual HTTP responses from the .NET cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

I have an ASP.NET MVC controller with a method that returns a file and is decorated with [HttpGet].

The first time it is called it gets the file and before returning it has the code:

```
ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(7));
ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
```

Subsequent requests to this [HttpGet] method return the file from the cache, so the method is not even reached on the HTTP request.

Elsewhere is code that deletes these files from the file system, but subsequent requests pull the response from the cache, so the files can still be downloaded.

How can I remove these items from the cache when I delete the files?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a code to check every time if the file exists on a specific location and then return a file from cache.

Or

if your code for deleting the file exist in the same application then you can add a code to clear the cache after the file is deleted.

Comment: I considered both of these options but don't know how to do either. First one: my code is never reached so I can't check if the file exists. Second one: I don't know if clearing the whole cache is safe and I don't know how to clear just a part of the cache. Either way, I don't know how.